# iPhone network game programming

Tags: iphone, network-programming

I'm interested in writing an iPhone game which uses the network to allow users on different iPhones to play against each other. I'm looking for an example of a game with source code which does this. I need some simple examples and documentation. Where should I look? I'm brand new to iPhone programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid just using GameKit, or you want to use the local wireless network alongside GameKit, the people who made BeamIt have very kindly published the source code for us all.

http://arctouch.com/beamit/developers/

Answer (score 1):

For GameKit (peer-to-peer via Bluetooth), there is Apple's sample application [GKTank](https://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/GKTank/index.html).  If you're interested in Bonjour discovery and communication over the local network, Apple has the sample application [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WiTap/).

Answer (score 0):

That is a big ask :)

A book you might find useful (as it has recipes for most of what you'll need to do) is Erica Sadun's excellent "IPhone Developer's Cookbook"

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Most of the pieces that you need have examples on the apple site. You'll just have to put them together.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/