# Remote Procedure Calls in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, rpc

How to you do remote procedure calls in iOS? Can anyone refer me to tutorials?

Comment: RPC between two iPads like an RPC framework, or passing raw socket messages, etc. Similar to JSON + RPC in python. I need to know how to do it on both the client/server side.

Comment: I meant, what are you trying to do at a very high level? Are the two iPads on the same network? Is this for a multiplayer game?

Comment: Yes, this is a for a game and the two iPads will need to communicate with each other. They will be on the same network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone network game programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078812/iphone-network-game-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peer-to-peer connections between two iOS devices? You're going to want to use GameKit.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1